# How to chaange my as_json method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Now i have used the as_json method like this in my model

```
  def as_json(options = {})
{
    id: id,
    diary_id: diary_id,
    title: title,
    post_date_gmt: date,
    post_content: strip_tags(content),
    smiley_id: smiley_id,
    author_id: user_id,
    author_name: user.display_name,
    attachments: filter_attachments(options[:version]),
    root_comments: format_comments(nested_comments.arrange(:order => :created_at)),
    post_readings: post_readings.size,
    is_read: read_by(options[:current_user])
}
end
```

I need to change this structure a bit as follows, Actually i want group this array by the date.

```
{
  date_01: {
    [post1], [post2], [post3]
   },
  date_02: {
    [post1], [post2], [post3]
   }
}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue as follows

```
post_dates = (no_of_days.days.ago.to_date..(date_as_string.to_date + no_of_days.days)).map{ |date| date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }

# Arrange posts details under each date
  i = 0
  post_dates.each do |post_date|
    posts_grouped_by_date[i] = {:post_date => post_date, :posts_for_date => diary.posts_for_date(Date.parse(post_date)  )}
    i = i + 1
  end

render json: posts_grouped_by_date.sort_by {|hash| hash['post_date']}.as_json(current_user: current_user)
```

Answer (score -1):

replace the values of data keys to an array of arrays. like below.

```
{
  date_01: [
    [post1], [post2], [post3]
   ],
  date_02: [
    [post1], [post2], [post3]
   ]
}
```